# Windows update failing

Tags: update, windows-10

For weeks I get message that I need to update my windows phone.

However, all the time it fails because I have too less memory.

The problem is, most memory is involved in the OS part, which I cannot access.

And the few applications I still have on my phone (not SD), I cannot change to the SD card, neither remove.

To make it worse, all apps from my SD card are gone after a format and the backup does not work.

Comment: Have you any photos or music stored on your device that you can temporarily move off?

Comment: I don't have any pics, movies, photos, online maps etc on my phone ... all is on my SD card.

Comment: Actually I even removed some apps (now there is about 2.5 GB of apps on my telephone, and except for maybe 100 MB I cannot remove them because they are system dependent  (not able to remove). Also the system files is 4.5 GB. Having just a bit left, getting all the time messages that the storage is full and I cannot easily remove apps, afraid if I remove WhatsApp that I cannot get all info back ... having bad experiences with backups too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.5 GB of system files? I can guess it's been more than 10 years you have been using your windows phone.

What you can try is, if you can afford it, doing a hard reset, to bring back the space taken by the system files to a normal of 3 GB. `From the phone go to: Settings > System Setting > About > Reset your phone`. Keep the phone plugged in till the process is completed.

Worrying about your messages on Whatsapp? There are OneDrive data upload systems both in system settings for a lot of apps. Some might not have, but the messages on Whatsapp can be backed up from a service in 'Whatsapp's settings' itself.

Having trouble in backing stuff up? You can even take offline backups of individual apps. This is a bit difficult to do, but yet if you want to know, comment below.

This answer was related to Windows 10 OS. If your phone is Windows Phone 8, the answer would a bit different. Comment below for me to change it. If this answer helped you, do give me an upvote, and mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but I only have the phone for about 2 years (Windows 10). I think it's downloading the upgrades several times without throwing them away ... I removed FB Messenger (300MB) and still only 100 MB left or even less.

Maybe I should indeed reinitialize my whole telephone ... but when I can miss it for some days.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget the offline maps. Quite big, only stored on phone if you have no phone 10 which allows you storing on SD. Managed in settings.

Comment: See comment above ... no maps, filespictures movies etc on the telephone itself, all on SD card (which is recently formatted and again gives corruption errors).